# Create a table in rails and add foreign key constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a table `students` with field `ward_id` and I have to create a table named `guardian_users` with fields `id,ward_id`,`email`,`guardian_id`,`hashed_password` etc.

Now I have to add constraint `foreign key`. Any update/delete/edit/insertion in students should have same effect on guardian_users.

How can I do that in rails 2.3.5?

Table students exists but other one doesn't exist yet.

Comment: No issues,but still you can comment

Comment: "should have same effect on" - try searching for cascading deletes.

Comment: @apneadiving: FYI, that's a fairly useless comment. If you feel that way, why say anything?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll either need the [foreign_key_migrations](https://github.com/harukizaemon/redhillonrails/tree/master/foreign_key_migrations/) plugin or the `#execute` method. Assuming you go with the plugin:

```
class CreateGuardianUsersTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table(:guardian_users) do |table|
      table.timestamps # I find them useful; YMMV
      table.integer :guardian_id
      table.integer :ward_id, :null => false, :references => [:students, :id]
      table.string :email
      table.string :heahead_password
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :guardian_users
  end
end
```

And in your models:

```
class GuardianUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many guardian_users:, :foreign_key => 'ward_id', :class_name => 'GuardianUser', :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Answer (score -2):

You're going to have to generate your migration first to build the guardian_users table. You can read up on migrations from the rails docs and doing FK's. You will also need to associate any models that represent the two of these entities with things like has_many or belongs_to.